# remove append in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am on select options which when selected, a new input area popup, but right now I am figuring out how to remove/undo the input area. I found that use .remove might be useful but I am not sure how to construct the script code.

```js
$("#dropdownlist").change(function() {
  var numInputs = $(this).val();

  if (numInputs == 2) {
    $("#inputArea").append('Student ID<input type="text" name="userid" >');
  } else if (numInputs == 3) {
    $("#inputArea").append('Lecturer ID<input type="text" name="userid" >');
  } else if (numInputs == 4) {
    $("#inputArea").append('Staff ID<input type="text" name="userid" >');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <select name="" id="dropdownlist" required>
    <option>Select category</option>
    <option value=1>Interviewee</option>
    <option value=2>Student</option>
    <option value=3>Lecturer</option>
    <option value=4>Staff</option>
  </select>
<div id="inputArea"></div>
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would say you should look at [`empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty) if you just want to remove what you added during the last `change` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than repeating lots of code you could simplify things and use an object to perform a lookup on the select value.

```js
$("#dropdownlist").change(function() {

    $("#inputArea").html('');   //clear the output
    
    const cats={
        2:'Student',
        3:'Lecturer',
        4:'Staff'
    }
    let i=$(this).val();
    let cat=cats.hasOwnProperty(i) ? cats[i] : false;
    
    if( cat ){
        $("#inputArea").append(`${cat} ID<input type="text" name="userid" >`);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="cat" id="dropdownlist" required>
  <option>Select category</option>
  <option value=1>Interviewee</option>
  <option value=2>Student</option>
  <option value=3>Lecturer</option>
  <option value=4>Staff</option>
</select>


<div id='inputArea'></div>
```

Comment: this works, thanks for sharing, bless you.

Comment: Why is this an improvement? You could go a step further and use the object to generate the dropdown. Otherwise no real point

Answer (score 0):

try this

Just show and hide

```js
$("#dropdownlist").change(function() {
  var numInputs = $(this).val()-1; 
  $("#inputArea label").hide();
  if (numInputs!=-1) $("#inputArea label").eq(numInputs).show()
  
});
```

```css
#inputArea label { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <select name="" id="dropdownlist" required>
    <option>Select category</option>
    <option value="0">Interviewee</option>
    <option value="1">Student</option>
    <option value="2">Lecturer</option>
    <option value="3">Staff</option>
  </select>
<div id="inputArea">
  <label>Student ID<input type="text" name="userid" ></label>
  <label>Lecturer ID<input type="text" name="userid" ></label>
  <label>Staff ID<input type="text" name="userid" ></label>
</div>
```

Comment: this works, thanks for sharing, bless you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.empty()` method to clear your input area.

```js
$("#dropdownlist").change(function() {
  var numInputs = $(this).val();

  if (numInputs == 2) {
    $("#inputArea").append('Student ID<input type="text" name="userid" >');
  } else if (numInputs == 3) {
    $("#inputArea").append('Lecturer ID<input type="text" name="userid" >');
  } else if (numInputs == 4) {
    $("#inputArea").append('Staff ID<input type="text" name="userid" >');
  }
});


function removeAll() {
  
   $("#inputArea").empty();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <select name="" id="dropdownlist" required>
    <option>Select category</option>
    <option value=1>Interviewee</option>
    <option value=2>Student</option>
    <option value=3>Lecturer</option>
    <option value=4>Staff</option>
  </select>
<div id="inputArea"></div>

<input type="button" value="Undo" onClick="removeAll()">
```

Comment: this works, thanks for sharing, bless you.